# What's wrong with my code? (ERC721: mint to the zero address) calling from Remix is good, calling from my script is failed

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development

#### answer:

It's a bug on goerli.  never use Goerli as your testnet.

#### origin question:

I have deploy an contract at: `https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x39c810abf2fb7f1e6db14db3e9a6f08e2daeab78`

it's abi is:

```
[{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function","constant":true},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"tokenURI","type":"string"}],"name":"mintNFT","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
```

and source code is:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract BigBigBanana is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

  constructor() ERC721("Big Big Banana", "BBB") {}
  function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256){
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _safeMint(recipient, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
    return newItemId;
  }

  // This is the core method
  function mint() public returns (uint256){
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _safeMint(address(msg.sender), newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, "https://bigbanana.infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/QmX6RYeTT8W4MymKaY6eBtoReHCFkVTV2XByctjV91aERu");
    return newItemId;
  }
}
```

and it can be successfully called via Remix:

[image]

But if I call it via my javascript file, it would failed:

source code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const fs = require('fs')

async function main(file_name_without_suffix, contract_address){
  const { abi } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("build/contracts/" +file_name_without_suffix+'.json'))

  const network = process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK

  // step1. 初始化web3 实例，增加json rpc server
  const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      `https://${network}.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID}`
    )
  )

  // step2. 创建signer
  const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(  process.env.SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY)
  web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer)

  // step3. 创建contract, abi是关键
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract( abi, contract_address)

  let result = ''
  result = await contract.methods.name().call()
  console.info("name: ", result)
  result = await contract.methods.symbol().call()
  console.info("symbol: ", result)

  let tx = ''
  //tx = await contract.methods.mint('0xc0dD5021e298dB57bEF361C735cd1C04cef2E48A')
  tx = await contract.methods.mint()
  result = await tx
    .send({from: signer.address, gas: await tx.estimateGas()})
    .once("transactionHash" , (txHash) => {
      console.info("mining transaction...", txHash)
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
      console.info("--- on error: ", error)
    })
  console.info("mint result: ", result)
}

require('dotenv').config()

main("BigBigBanana", "0x39c810abf2fb7f1e6db14db3e9a6f08e2daeab78").then( () => process.exit(0) )
```

result:

```
{"type":"Error","message":"Returned error: execution reverted: ERC721: mint to the zero address","stack":"Error: Returned error: execution reverted: ERC721: mint to the zero address\n    at Object.ErrorResponse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got the answer:  it's a bug on GOERLI network. (especially when you call contract method via nodejs )

It's so strange that GOERLI network gives me many strange bugs. so my suggestion is quite simple:

use rinkeby, use fuji, use ganache, use hardhat, use other EVM network.